# How to increase one variable depending on another?

Tags: java, android

I understand that the question is stupid and it is quite possible that I will understand how to do it with a fresh mind in the morning, but unfortunately I need it right now.

There are two variables:

```
int simbol_lenght = 0;
int count_simbol_up = 0;
```

`simbol_lenght` during operation, it can take any value from 0 and above. How to make sure that every time this variable is greater than 2, `count_simbol_up` increased by +1?

Comment: Wherever simbol_length is increased, check if it is greater than 2. Then increment by 1.

Comment: May be you want something `if(simbol_lenght > 2) { count_simbol_up++ }`

Answer (score 1):

Something simple would be to wrap the logic to set its value in a method:

```
void setSimbolLenght(int val) {
  if (val > 2) {
    ++count_simbol_up;
  }
  simbol_lenght = val;
}
```

Whenever you would usually set its value directly...

```
simbol_lenght = aVal;
```

Call the method instead:

```
setSimbolLenght(aVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

every time you can use if condition, if, if-else is a conditional control statement based on the condition(boolean) the respective statements will get executed and other statement ignored for that moment. please try if condition like below

```
if (simbol_lenght >2) { 
   statements to be executed here 
} else {
   statements to be executed
}
```

i will go with simple example here for better understanding,

```
if(isApple) { System.out.println("its an apple");}
else { System.out.println("its not an apple");}
```